# NSDateFormatter setDateFormat non-zero-padded month number

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter, zero-pad

Is it possible to get the non-zero-padded month number using `setDateFormat`?

If not, could you provide an alternative solution?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `M` instead of `MM` in the format string. If you use two letters, you specify that the result should have two digits, if you don't, the result can have one or two digits.